# LLVM : recognize reference

Tags: pointers, reference, llvm

How can i recognize in llvm taking the address of variable. For example:

```
int g;
int *v;
int *test() {
   v = &g       
   func(&g)
   return &g
}
```

In LLVM is getting address:

```
store i32* @g, i32** @v, align 4
call i32 @func(i32* @g)
ret i32* @g
```

I want to recognize if the address is taken or the value of variable is taken. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Names of global variables are always addresses in LLVM.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to recognize when the address of global variable is stored or etc. instead of value of this global variable. For example alias analysis can helps, but i don't know which method or what use to recognize this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be a way to tell this in general. Taking the address of a certain things might be optimized away in certain instances. The compiler might choose to pass some things by pointer even though it wasn't written that way.

You might have better luck using libclang an operating on the c++ syntax tree, I think this is possible.

Comment: But I want to recognize when the address of global variable is stored or etc. instead of value of this global variable. For example alias analysis can helps, but i don't know which method or what use to recognize this situation.

Comment: @JaroKollár GlobalVariable always has PointerType and it represents an address. The same thing goes for any other "allocated" memory. in this sense, the explicitly defined variables in source code should always be of (trivial) pointer type since they will be resident in memory(unless they've been optimized out). furthermore, i guess that several alias analysis(e.g., basicaa?) is calculated by "def/use" of pointers, not the other way around.  what'll take the address? as long as the AllocaInst/GlobalVariable is not "loaded", any other Instructions that reference/use it will.